# How to extract IP addresses from a single long String in Java

Tags: java, android, string, ip-address, android-logcat

I am writing an android app to do a traceroute command.

Right now when the traceroute executes it puts the console output into a very long single string. This is done by the following code:

```
    public void runAsRoot(String[] cmds) throws Exception {


    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
    InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
    for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
        os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
        int readed = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[4096];

        // if cmd requires an output
        // due to the blocking behaviour of read(...)
        boolean cmdRequiresAnOutput = true;
        if (cmdRequiresAnOutput) {
            while( is.available() <= 0) {
                try { Thread.sleep(10000); } catch(Exception ex) {}  //timeout.. gotta watch this carefully.
            }

            while( is.available() > 0) {

                readed = is.read(buff);
                if ( readed <= 0 ) break;
                String seg = new String(buff,0,readed);
                System.out.println("#> "+seg);
                ListofIPs = seg;


            }
        }
    }        
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
}
```

The output of this strings looks like this:
[image: logcat output after printing the string]

What I want to do is take this output and extract only the IP addresses and put them in order into an array.
This is where I am at a loss of even where to begin. I'm thinking some type of String manipulation but don't know where to start.

If anyone has any idea or pointers I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the `.split()` method of the `String` class.

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions? If not, check here, it is just what you need: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex

Comment: Read line by line..use `.split(" ")` and second element would be IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to delete the 1st line and then try to using [String split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) by spaces. This way you know the IP is located in the 1,5,9,.. `(1+4*n_iteration)` or you can go split by "ms" then split by spaces again.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex).

In your case, the code would look something like this:

```
seg.split("[^((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}]");
```

I did not test it, but it should do the job. You can tinker a more elegant solution in no time.

Comment: won't this delete the ips and leave me with the rest?

Comment: no, because I added[^...]which means *not* this. Basically, its a bit hacky: the expression is everything *except* the IPs and the IPs will be your array elements.